# Number Of Permutations With Specific Characteristics

Tags: combinatorics

You have a pile of $n$ distinct objects. You select $r>n$ times from the pile, each time replacing the object you picked (assume each selection is independent, and each object is equally likely to be chosen).

What is the probability you select each of the $n$ objects at least once?

My thought process is that there are $n^r$ possible permutations of selections, so the question comes down to how many different ways you can select $n$ distinct objects in $r$ trials from a group of size $n$.

To explore the question, I looked at a small example-- selecting from 3 objects in 3 trials. There are 27 possible arrangements of selections, of which 6 contain all 3 objects so the probability is 6/27. But where does that 6 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process can be described by a function $f$ from $\{1,\dots,r\}$ to $n$ where $f(i)$ is the object picked in selection $i$.

We want to calculate the fraction of these functions that are surjective.

In order to do this we wish to count how many of these functions are surjective.

This is one of the problems solved in the $12$-fold method.

The number of surjective functions is ${r\brace n}n!$ where $\brace$ denotes the stirling coefficient of the second kind.

This is because every partition of $\{1,\dots, r\}$ into $n$ parts yields $r!$ surjections.

Therefore the desired probability is

$$\frac{{r\brace n}n!}{n^r}$$

Comment: Thanks, had never heard of that notation before. I take it there is no nice way/trick to compute the stirling coefficient for large values of n and r?

Comment: Yes there is a recursion similar to the one for binomial coefficients, and also an inclusion-exclusion expression.